# F# - cancellation token works for async{} but not for task{}

Tags: f#, task, f#-async

When I run this code-block using the **async{}** computation expression:

```
let tokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource()

let runAsync() =
    async {
        while true do
            do! Async.Sleep(1000 * 1)
            printfn "hello"
    }

Async.Start(runAsync(), tokenSource.Token)
```

...and then run `tokenSource.Cancel()`, the executing process is cancelled, as expected.

However, when I run this extremely similar code-block using **task{}**:

```
let tokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource()

let rec runTask() =
    task {
        while true do
            do! Task.Delay(1000 * 1)
            printfn "hello"
    }
let run () = runTask () :> Task

Task.Run(run, tokenSource.Token)
```

...and then run `tokenSource.Cancel()`, the executing process is NOT cancelled.

**Why does the cancellation token function as expected for async{} but not for task{}?**

Comment: Note that I ran this experiment in F# Interactive, in case that is relevant.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That’s by design. For performance and other reasons, tasks are deliberately hot started, while `Async` is cold-started. Cold-started asynchronous operations can be given a cancellation token. After a task is started, which is immediate in the case of `task`, it cannot be given a CT anymore.

What you need is `cancellableTask` from the [IcedTask library](https://github.com/TheAngryByrd/IcedTasks).

Note that it’s fine to have an `Async`  inside a `task` CE. That nested `Async`  can be cancelled just like any other Async (similarly, it’s fine to pass the token to `Task.DeLay`, which *will work* for this scenario).

Note also that `Task.Run` in your code is redundant and should typically not be used. Calling `runTask()` (which shouldn’t be `rec` btw) internally already calls `Task.Run` (or equivalent), so all you’re doing is wrapping it in another task. Since CTs are not automatically passed on to child tasks, the CT doesn’t have effect.

And one more thing, if you do need `rec` in your real world code, be advised that tasks (from `task` CE) are not tail recursive, while `async` is. This may change soon, as [this change is strongly considered in the near future](https://github.com/fsharp/fslang-suggestions/issues/1006).

Comment: thx for the tip on `rec` - I suspected that was probably the case for `task`, so I changed both examples not to use recursion so as to remove that as a possible explanation. But I forgot to delete the keyword